# Proof of Zimmer's cocycle super-rigidity theorem

Tags: gr.group-theory, lie-groups, ds.dynamical-systems, geometric-group-theory, ergodic-theory

I was reading the proof of Zimmer's cocycle super-rigidity theorem from the book 'Ergodic theory and semi-simple groups' by Robert Zimmer (Theorem 5.2.5, page 98). But I am not able to understand it. Could someone explain the main ideas of the proof of the theorem? It will be sufficient if someone explains the proof in the situation when there is a cocycle $\alpha: G \times X \rightarrow H$, where $G=SL_n(\mathbb{R})$ ($n\geq 3$) , $H=SO(n,1)$ or $SL_m(\mathbb{R})$ and $G$ is acting by a probability measure preserving action on $(X,\mu)$.

Thank you in advance!